# Catchable fatal error in formatting.php

Tags: database, errors

I'm running a WordPress 4.4.2. I have one site that's working fine. When I went to set up another site, I got the following error upon trying to save the "general" settings page:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /{site-url}/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1025'
```

Before saving the settings, I deleted the existing sample page and sample post and created a new page. Didn't touch anything else.

After researching the problem, I have done all of the following:

- Deactivated all plugins (error persists)
- Changed to default WordPress theme (error persists)
- Reinstalled current WordPress version (error persists)
- Upgraded the network (error persists)
- Checked Options tables in phpMyAdmin, no fishy strings exist
- Compared Options table between the site with and without the error, they seem identical
- Run the WP-Optimize plugin

I notice that I can only save values to the Options table from phpMyAdmin. When I try via the browser (ex. `wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=#`), the options don't save.

When I set an additional site to test, I don't have this problem. Obviously, I can just delete the site and start over, but a) the problem exists also on my default multisite, and b) I'd like to understand what's causing it.

Is this a bug? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This would almost have to be a plugin or theme problem.  Somewhere a query is returning an error and instead of handling the error, the error object it is being passed to `sanitize_text_field()` or something similar.  I know you said you deactivated plugins and used a default theme but I can't help but think there's a call being made from outside WP core.  

Can you provide a stack trace of the error?

Comment: The stack trace should help you find the call passing the error object. You can then examine that object for more information.

Comment: The function in question the warning occurs at is `wp_check_invalid_utf8`, you should try extracting a fresh copy of WordPress over the top of your existing install, if using a standard theme and no plugins gives you this error then this implies modifications have been made to WordPress itself, or mu-plugins and drop in files are present

Comment: Check whether you have a `mu-plugins` folder. A while ago I had some weird problems with BlueHost. It seems that they add automatically a plugin there to integrate with some app in their cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I cleaned the content of the row called `theme_mods_YOURTHEMENAME` (into the table `wp-options`)

I copy/past the content I had with a previous backup.

Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You havent included all lines of the error page. Only that line is not enough.
As a quick solution, you can insert in `wp-includes\formatting.php` 1025 line:

```
var_dump($string); 
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
exit;
```

and see what you get.